# Switch to an other slide with LayerSlider

Tags: php, wordpress

i need different classes for icons symbolized by squares, green one for 1st slide, red one for 2nd slide, etc..

i want to do like this with layer slider.

[image]

I nothing found from the Internet for that so how could i do this.

Comment: you can customize carousel slider.

Comment: how can i do this i don not have any idea ?

Comment: see this link http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-slider-with-caption.html

Comment: i am not using flex slider i used layer slider and i want to be do changes (custom) in layer slider.

Comment: what you have you tried?.

Comment: can you post your layer slider code?

Comment: sorry i do not have code for it ,  layer slider provided plugin setting and i seen all setting of layer slider but i could not find any thing what i want.

Comment: i am  searching  custom navigation for this.

Comment: why did you not understand i used layer slider and i want to make custom changes only layer slider not any else plugin.

Comment: can post layerslider link which is used?

Comment: Layer slider http://wpdemo.web-dorado.com/layer-slider/

Comment: there is an option to add class. do you want dynamically?

Comment: yes i want to it dynamically.

Comment: You can modify the plugin in loop. Right?

Comment: yes i want to modify plugin and i want slide move as per i attached my image in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129610/discussion-between-vel-and-maddy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the modifications then add this in the functions.php file:

```
// slider nav
add_action('wp_footer', 'ava_custom_nav_script');
function ava_custom_nav_script(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('.ls_nav_1').click(function() {
        $('#layerslider_1_1').layerSlider(2);
    });

    $('.ls_nav_2').click(function() {
        $('#layerslider_1_1').layerSlider(1);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}
```

In the advance layout editor, add this code in a code block:

```
<a href="#" class="ls_nav_1">Change to slide 2</a></br>
<a href="#" class="ls_nav_2">Change to slide 1</a>
```

First button will link to the second slide and the second button will go back to the first slide.

Comment: wc  :) I happy to helped you!